# fancybox 2 open image generated from php

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

We are doing some logic in php to output the image, so the url doesn't have .jpg/etc

This is causing fancybox to exit at the point below where its checking the type. What is the correct way to fix this?

```
_start: function (index) {
            var coming = {},
                obj,
                href,
                type,
                margin,
                padding;

            index = getScalar( index );
            obj   = F.group[ index ] || null;

            if (!obj) {
                return false;
            }

            coming = $.extend(true, {}, F.opts, obj);

            // Convert margin and padding properties to array - top, right, bottom, left
            margin  = coming.margin;
            padding = coming.padding;

            if ($.type(margin) === 'number') {
                coming.margin = [margin, margin, margin, margin];
            }

            if ($.type(padding) === 'number') {
                coming.padding = [padding, padding, padding, padding];
            }

            // 'modal' propery is just a shortcut
            if (coming.modal) {
                $.extend(true, coming, {
                    closeBtn   : false,
                    closeClick : false,
                    nextClick  : false,
                    arrows     : false,
                    mouseWheel : false,
                    keys       : null,
                    helpers: {
                        overlay : {
                            closeClick : false
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            // 'autoSize' property is a shortcut, too
            if (coming.autoSize) {
                coming.autoWidth = coming.autoHeight = true;
            }

            if (coming.width === 'auto') {
                coming.autoWidth = true;
            }

            if (coming.height === 'auto') {
                coming.autoHeight = true;
            }

            /*
             * Add reference to the group, so it`s possible to access from callbacks, example:
             * afterLoad : function() {
             *     this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
             * }
             */

            coming.group  = F.group;
            coming.index  = index;

            // Give a chance for callback or helpers to update coming item (type, title, etc)
            F.coming = coming;

            if (false === F.trigger('beforeLoad')) {
                F.coming = null;

                return;
            }

            type = coming.type;
            href = coming.href;

            if (!type) {
                F.coming = null;

                //If we can not determine content type then drop silently or display next/prev item if looping through gallery
                if (F.current && F.router && F.router !== 'jumpto') {
                    F.current.index = index;

                    return F[ F.router ]( F.direction );
                }

                return false; // this returns false
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding attribute but it should really just default to image type if its not able to auto work this out.

```
<a href="" data-fancybox-type="image" class="fancybox">
```

Comment: This why FAQs were invented. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support ==> FAQ tab ==> No.5

Comment: @JFK I dont think they could be anymore hidden away when I didn't click support